# In WSE services, with custom types, do constructors work on the consuming client's side?

Tags: .net, web-services, wse

I have custom types in a WSE web service.

the consuming client can't seem to see my constructor when instantiating a class, is this normal?

Comment: blowdart is correct. Are you also aware that WSE is obsolete? WCF should be used for all new web service development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Web services do not pass objects, they pass messages. The class on the client side is simply a holder for properties on that message, it will not have implementation beyond that.